# Could not run emulator on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just installed android studio version 3.0.1.
And then following tutorial "Building your first app"
I am doing exactly what the tutorial said. but then when i tried to run "app", the emulator show up for a while, less than 1 sec i think and then its gone. 
I got an error "Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)". What does this error mean? I have been searching on google and stack overflow for the similar problem, but still can't find the solution. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Delete the AVD from disk and try to create it again.
To do so: Open the "Tools" menu of Android Studio
Click on "Android", then on "AVD manager".
Select the emulator that fails to start, and click the triangle at the far right of the row.
Click on "Delete".
Re-create the AVD using 'Add virtual device'.